# How to close the new tab and return to the first tab in Robot Framework?

Tags: tabs, robotframework

My test scenario clicks the button that follows to the new tab of the browser, after verifying that we got the right page I need to close this tab and return to the first tab. How could I close the actual tab? I tried to use Close Window, but it closes the entire browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code can help you open new tab and close that's new tab by and return to your first tab.

```
*** Test Cases ***
T1
    Open Browser    ${URL}   ${BROWSER}
    click element   name=btn
    ${title_var}        Get Window Titles
    Select Window       title=@{title_var}[1]       
    close window
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code to close active window and back to main window

${windowhandles}=   Get Window Handles

Switch Window   ${windowhandles}[1]

close window

Switch Window   ${windowhandles}[0]